# To what extent was literary criticism being applied to scientific works at the time Darwin's Plots was written?

Tags: literary-criticism, charles-darwin, science-and-technology-studies, gillian-beer, darwins-plots

I'm reading Gillian Beer's *Darwin's Plots: Evolutionary Narrative in Darwin, George Eliot and Nineteenth-Century Fiction*. This book is essentially a work of literary criticism of Darwin's theory of evolution. It traces the Darwin's literary influences as well as Darwin's impact on literature. It also features a close reading of Darwin's work, and argues that ideas can't be separated from the language they are contained in. It's a really interesting work and it's worth reading if you're interested in Literature.

One thing that I didn't get from the introduction was to what extent Beer was doing something new by applying literary criticism to a scientific work. Was this something that has always been done, is Beer the first person to have done this, or is Beer part of an emerging tradition but not necessarily the first?

Comment: This has probably not been answered because it is so vague. What is literary criticism? What is science? What is a scientific work? People have reviewed science books, paying attention to their literary value, for a long time. Analyses of Aristotle (one of the first scientists) have long focused on his language and rhetorical structures. Deconstructionists and structuralists have looked at scientific texts as well as pseudoscience such as Freud. Philosophers of science have debated the structure of a scientific paper. Biographers have attempted to draw life lessons from scientific writing.